# How to set a generic model in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I have a model class like this:

```
  public class GenericModel<T> where T : BaseTest
  {
      //Ctor

      public List<T> TestList{get;set;}
  }
```

I can work ok with this becouse I set it in my controllers and my views.
But i have a Partial View wich can be used by all controllers.

I would like to know if i can do somethinf like this in that partial view:

```
@model GenericModel<T>
```

Without specifing the generic type. What can i do here? Use an interface or something?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to define it with `T`, because it needs an actual type to follow the `@model` statement.

In my experience, using refactor in visual studio, extract an interface for `GenericModel` say `IGenericModel` and for `BaseTest`, say `IBaseTest`, then your model statements becomes:

```
@model IGenericModel<IBaseTest>
```

update:

Just to clarify, the interfaces to extract could be something like (note the `out` for variance, it will make your life easier if you use it):

```
public interface IGenericModel<out T> where T : IBaseTest
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll(); // just as an example
}

public interface IBaseTest
{
    T Property { get; }
}
```

Comment: @ggui I don't think I understood you, but I added some explicit example to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I've used many times is to create a non-generic base-class for your Generic, making it:

```
public class GenericModel<T> : NormalModel where T:BaseTest
{
}
```

Your base class could be something like:

```
public abstract class NormalModel
{
    public abstract IList ItemsList { get; }
}
```

(If it's this simple you'd probably just make it an interface, but I'm assuming there's more to it and some of the GenericModel is not dependent on T and might go in the base class).

Then your view can use the `NormalModel` and you'll just have to override it in your `GenericModel` and provide it with your `TestList` (and anything else that you need to use in your view).